# Convert string[] to string before serializing

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

This is part of my code:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
```

I have added my data in dictionary, and serializing it by:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict)
```

I want to convert string[] to string, if there is only 1 item in string array.

So if the output is:

```
{
"Number": ["123"],
"Names": ["John", "Harry"]
}
```

I want it to be as:

```
{
"Number": "123",
"Names": ["John", "Harry"]
}
```

Since there is only 1 item in the array of "123". So, how to solve this?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this? If it is possible to have more than one item, but in some instances there is only one item, then it should remain a string[]. In some cases it is just an array of one item. This way other parsers will able to interpret your JSON better.

Comment: no idea what your use case is, but i strongly recommend not doing this as this is likely to cause a lot of headache to the people trying to read your json.
If it always contains only one value, why not change it to string right away?
Or create an itermediate class for serialization.

Comment: This makes it unnecessarily complicated both in serialization and deserialization for you and third parties. However, you could make a `Name` property and a `Names` property, where the former is only filled if there is only one name and the latter only if there are multiple names, the other is always set to null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is:

```
var newDict = dict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
    x => x.Value.Length == 1 ? (object)x.Value.Single() : (object)x.Value);
```

And then serialise `newDict`.

The majority of the logic lies in the second argument. I decide whether to use the single element of the value part of the KVP, or the whole string array, based on the length.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own `JsonConverter` as below.

As if you don't want to re-create a `Dictionary` everytime.

```
    public class SingleElementArrayJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            string[] arr = value as string[];
            if (arr == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
            }

            if(arr.Length == 1)
            {
                JToken.FromObject(arr[0]).WriteTo(writer);
            }
            else
            {
                JArray.FromObject(arr).WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool CanWrite => true;

        public override bool CanRead => false;

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(string[]);
    }
```

This Converter should be used like this:

```
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, new SingleElementArrayJsonConverter());
```